# Two hours or so after restarting my computer, some webpages don't load unless I restart again

Tags: windows, browser

**OS and computer type:** Windows 8.1 and Lenovo G505 laptop

**Further description:** In Chrome, after the computer is on for a while after being restarted, certain websites, e.g. StackExchange sites, my university's webmail, or its library's journal search page, simply display a "This webpage is not available", with the Chrome sad face in a page: [image: Chrome].

**Is it browser dependent?** On my computer, none of the browsers I have installed (Firefox, and Internet Explorer) can load the webpage either.

**What about other computers?** Other computers, for instance my desktop, can load the webpages just fine at the same time as when my computer cannot.

**Adware/malware?** I have run full scans and squashed any bugs with Malware Bytes, AVG Free and Windows Defender.

**What fixes the issue on your computer?** Restarting it, but not logging off and logging back in.

What's the issue here?

Comment: So all browsers stop working for all sites from a single computer after ~2 hours?

Comment: Wired or wifi? What about the 'working' computers?

Comment: What happens when you try and `ping` the website when it stops working ?

Comment: @BrianAdkins All browsers, for a select few websites, from a single computer, after ~2 hours.

Comment: @BrianAdkins My computer: wi-fi. Working computers: wired and wi-fi.

Comment: @Lawrence I will try it out and let you know!